# Nodejs Async Js : Validating URLs using async.forEach and async.map

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am using async.forEach for iterating over my URLs to check if the links are active or not.

*newLinks* contains links like {*www.google.com,www.nourl.com,www.xyz.com*}
I am expecting like after all the request are processed , I want a function to execute, which prints "Async Done".

But the console is giving the below results: 
"www.google.com is up", then 
"Async Done", then
"Done" and funally the two links
"www.nourl.com is up" and
"www.xyz.com is up"

So basically here, after the first url request , my code below is executing the function outside the async loop. I thought async will only allow the next piece of code to execute only after all the urls are validated.

```
async.forEach(webservicelinks, function(url, callback) {
    var Url = "url";
    var newLink = newLinks[0];
    var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': Url});
    proxiedRequest(url , function (error, response, body) {

      if(error){
        console.log('Err: '+ error);
      }
    if (!error) {
    if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202){
      console.log(url + ' is up!!');
      newLink.isActive = true;
    }

    if(response.statusCode == 301 || response.statusCode == 302){
      console.log(url + ' is redirecting us!!');
      return false;
    }

    if(response.statusCode == 401){
      console.log("you are unauthorized to " + link);
      return false;
    }else if (!(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202)){
      console.log(url + ' is down!!');
    }
    }
    });
    callback();
    }  , function(err, newLinks) {
    console.log ("Async Done")  ;
    });
    console.log ("Done")  ;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `eachOfSeries` method of `async.js`. I divided your code into functions to increase readability:

```
function validateAllLinks(webservicelinks, cb) {
    async.eachOfSeries(webservicelinks, validateLink, function (err) {

        if(err) {
            cb("Validation failed")
        } else {
            cb(null, "Success")
        }

    })

}

function validateLink(linkData, cb) {
    var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': linkData.linkUrl});
        proxiedRequest(linkData.linkUrl , function (error, response, body) {
            // some validation
            if(validated) {
                linkData.linkStatus = true
            }
        })
}

// usage:

validateAllLinks([{linkUrl: 'http://google.com', linkStatus: false}], console.log)
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I pass some other parameters other than url and cb in the validateLink method?
Like I want to pass the whole list of linkDataList(which is an array of linkData -> containing linkUrl and linkStatus and want to set linkStatus to true if linkUrl is working)?

Comment: Hi Thankyou, I did likewise, but the issue is like only the first url is validated and the rest is not executing. Not sure why.